# $\phi : A^n \to A^n $ be a surjective $A$-linear map then $\phi$ is injective as well.

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1,$ and $\phi : A^n \to A^n $ be a surjective $A$-linear map for some natural number $n.$ Then show that  $\phi$ is injective as well.

Tensoring with $A/m$ for some maximal ideal $m$ in $A$ will give that tensor map is onto and being $A/m$ linear is injective. But from this map I cannot recover $\phi$ and claim that $\phi$ is also injective. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that it follows from a general result by Vasconcelos: let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $u : M \to M$ be a surjective $R$-module endomorphism. Show that $u$ is injective

Comment: I know that..converting $M$ as an $R[X]$ module using $u$, that proof goes. Here I am looking for  some independent proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me where i am wrong :
We have an exact sequence : $ 0 \to \ker(T) \to A^n \xrightarrow{\phi} A^n \to 0$ of $A$-modules. Now as $A^n$ is free the sequence splits, thus $ A^n = A^n \oplus \ker(T)$. And now tensoring  with $A/m$ now might help in adding the dimensions and then by Nakayama lemma we can show that $\ker(T) =0$.

Also thinking in the way you have done , we get that $ \phi(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)= 0 $  when on tensoring these $a_i$'s lie in m for every maximal ideal m. That implies all the $a_i$'s lie in the Jacobson radical $\mathfrak{R}$. Now consider $ \ker (T)$. We see that $\mathfrak{R}\ker(T) = \ker (T)$. Thus by Nakayama lemma then $\ker(T)  = 0 $. (I might be a bit wrong here to so please correct me.)

Comment: In your first paragraph, to use Nakayama, $m$ must be the Jacobson radical rather than a maximal ideal. Does it still work well then?

Comment: Also, I am not even sure that $\ker(T)$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @JWL in Atiyah Mcdonald Ex 12 of modules  states that if we have a finitely generated $A$ module M and a surjective morphism $ \phi : M \to A^n$ ,then $ \ker(\phi)$ is finitey generated.

Comment: @JWL : As for your first comment, one way is to localize at every prime $\mathfrak p$ of $A$. If $N:= \ker(\phi)$, you'll get $N_{\mathfrak p} = 0, \; \forall \mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ which implies $N=0$.

Comment: @ Watson   May be the following happens. After tensoring with $A/m$ for some maximal ideal $m$(in the first paragraph) we have $N=mN$ where $N=ker(\phi)$ i.e., by NAK $Ann_{A}(N)+m=A$ for all maximal ideal $m.$ Now if $Ann_{A}(N)$ is proper ideal, it must be contained in some other maximal ideal which gives a contradiction. Thus $1\in Ann_{A}(N)$ and $N=0.$

Comment: @JWL About your second comment: the answerer wrote $ A^n = A^n \oplus \ker(T)$, but this means $ A^n \simeq A^n \oplus \ker(T)$. Then $\ker T$ is isomorphic to a quotient module of $A^n$.